# Manejo de consultas SQL con ELOQUENT

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hola buenas noches a todos, me voy iniciando en el framework de laravel aun ue antes he trabajado php como tal, algo que veo que se maneja diferente es que cuando se crea un controlador por defecto aparecen varios metodos y uno en especial es el store en el que veo que siempre se ejecutan las consultas, vengo de una forma de programar en la que se crea la conexión, las validaciones y metodos especificos para los distintos tipos de consultas que se van a realizar y en lo particular me ha confundido un poco esta forma en como se maneja, mi duda es si por ejemplo tengo varios formularios en los que los datos obtenidos se mandaran a tablas distintas ¿como es la mejor forma de implementarlo ya que no veo muy conveniente ocupar el mismo metodo para todo, muchas gracias por su tiempo la verdad es que este framework me ha confundido en varias cosas que aun estoy viendo como funcionan, un saludo

Comment: Hola! Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. Así como está planteada tu pregunta es muy difícil de responder y si alguien lo hace, seguramente sea una respuesta basada en su opinión, pues hay tantas formas de hacerlo como programadores.

Comment: muchas gracias por el comentario, lo tomare en cuenta, un saludo